# Limit point of sequence whose general term is $ \frac{1}{1\cdot n} + \frac{1}{2\cdot(n-1)}+\dots+\frac{1}{n\cdot1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find the limit point(s) of the sequence whose general term is given by:
$$a_n = \frac{1}{1\cdot n} + \frac{1}{2\cdot (n-1)}+\dots+\frac{1}{n\cdot 1}$$
**My observation:**

1. $\frac{1}{1\cdot n} + \frac{1}{2\cdot (n-1)}+\dots+\frac{1}{n\cdot 1} \gt \frac{1}{n\cdot n} + \frac{1}{n\cdot (n-1)}+\dots+\frac{1}{n\cdot 1}  \gt \frac{1}{n\cdot n} + \frac{1}{n\cdot n}+\dots+\frac{1}{n\cdot n} = \frac{1}{n}$.
2. The series with $a_n$ as the general term is divergent.

Intuitively I feel its a non- monotonic divergent sequence, but I am stuck at how to go further.
Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You needn't use a period symbol for multiplication, LaTeX & MatJax have a special command `\cdot` for it, which looks like this: `1\cdot n` → $1\cdot n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence, $a_n$, can be written

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k(n-k+1)}\\\\
&=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k-(n+1)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac2{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k 
\end{align}$$

It is easy to show that $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below by $0$.  So $a_n$ converges.  Moreover, from the integral test, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k \le \log(n)+1$$

Therefore, we see that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k(n-k+1)}=0$$

Comment: Was there a reason the downvoter would care to provide?